# Trying to delete api key but getting "await is only valid in async function"

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-sdk-js

I'm trying to delete api keys using AWS SDK JS, but I'm receiving this error message:

```
{
    "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
    "errorMessage": "SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function",
    "stack": [
        "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError: SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function",
        "    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:98:13)",
        "    at Object.module.exports.load (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:140:17)",
        "    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/index.js:36:30)",
        "    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:701:30)",
        "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)",
        "    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)",
        "    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)",
        "    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)",
        "    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)",
        "    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)"
    ]
}
```

I've tried to create a promise to delete, just like I did to select keys, but I think it might be a problem to do it inside a foreach.

My code:

```
let sendPromise = null;
let params = {
    includeValues: true,
    limit: 500
};
let dados = null;

sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().getApiKeys( params ).promise();

try {
    dados = await sendPromise;
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
    return criarResposta( 500, `{
        "message": "Erro interno"
    }` );
}

dados.items.forEach( chave => {
    const paramsDeletar = {
        apiKey: chave.id
    };

    sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().deleteApiKey( params ).promise();

    try {
        let dadosDeletar = await sendPromise;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error( err, err.stack );
        return criarResposta( 500, `{
            "message": "Erro interno"
        }` );
    }
});

return criarResposta( 200, JSON.stringify( dados ) );
```

Other thing, do I need to wait for all my promises individually or there is a way of wait for promise's bundle?
I can't not wait for my promise, because I'm using lambda, but I wish I could let them running together

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you better replace the forEach loop with a for loop, that way will be able to use the await in it:

```
...
for (const chave of dados.items) {
    const paramsDeletar = {
        apiKey: chave.id
    };

    sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().deleteApiKey( params ).promise();

    try {
        let dadosDeletar = await sendPromise;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error( err, err.stack );
        return criarResposta( 500, `{"message": "Erro interno"}` );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to make an async function for the use of async-await in Nodejs 
   You have to only async keyword in a forEach function

```
let sendPromise = null;
let params = {
    includeValues: true,
    limit: 500
};
let dados = null;

sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().getApiKeys( params ).promise();

try {
    dados = await sendPromise;
} catch(err) {
    console.error(err, err.stack);
    return criarResposta( 500, `{
        "message": "Erro interno"
    }` );
}

dados.items.forEach( async chave => {
    const paramsDeletar = {
        apiKey: chave.id
    };

    sendPromise = new AWS.APIGateway().deleteApiKey( params ).promise();

    try {
        let dadosDeletar = await sendPromise;
    } catch(err) {
        console.error( err, err.stack );
        return criarResposta( 500, `{
            "message": "Erro interno"
        }` );
    }
});

return criarResposta( 200, JSON.stringify( dados ) );
```

Comment: You can find some background on async/await functions [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: **Note: it will NOT WAIT for the deletion promise TO COMPLETE. As foreach loop doesn't support async function**